# Proving a set has integer extreme points

Tags: polyhedra, integer-programming, total-unimodularity

[image]

The hint says to use TU Properties, but I don't know how to express P as a matrix to use the properties

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Try inserting nonnegative slack variables into the inequalities (making them equalities), and then write the system of equalities in matrix notation.